Docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create endpoint openhands-app on network bridge:
I tried to install all hands ai on my machine and docker complained:
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create endpoint openhands-app on network bridge: failed to add the host (veth5d29652) <=> sandbox (vethbfd8b3b) pair interfaces: operation not supported.

Ive read it might have something to do with missing kernel modules, is it right?` If so any ideas about how to fix it? Can I just install the missing modules from pacman?
